# awk: print first column, then some values, and then all other columns

Tags: bash, awk

I want to print the first column, then a couple of columns with fixed values, like this command would do:

```
awk '{print $1,"1","2","1"}'
```

and then print all columns except the first after that... 
I know this command prints all but the first column:

```
awk '{$1=""; print $0}'
```

But that gets rid of the first column.

In other words, this:

```
3 5 2 2
3 5 2 2
3 5 2 2
3 5 2 2
```

Needs to become this:

```
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a loop to iterate through rest of the columns like this:

`awk '{print $1,"1","2","1";for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'`

As an example:

```
$echo "3  5  2  2" | awk 'BEGIN{ORS=""}{print $1,"1","2","1";for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
$
```

Edit1 :

```
$ echo "3  5  2  2" | awk 'BEGIN{ORS="\n";OFS="\n"}{print $1,"1","2","1 ";for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i" "}'
3
1
2
1
5
2
2
$
```

Edit2:

```
$ echo "3  5  2  2" | awk '{print $1,"1","2","1";for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) print $i}'
3 1 2 1
5
2
2
$
```

Edit3:

```
$ echo "3 5 2 2
3 5 2 2
3 5 2 2
3 5 2 2" | awk '{printf("%s %s ", $1,"1 2 1");for(i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf("%s ", $i); printf "\n"}'
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
```

Comment: Thanks! This almost works, except it seems to print everything in 1 line... (if you create multiple lines in your example command, he will print all rows in the first line)

Comment: for that you can use `ORS="\n"` and `OFS="\n"`

Comment: Unfortunately it then prints all values on a new line... If your original file consists of "3 5 2 2", but on four lines, can you get that to work? (i.e., create a new file with "3 1 2 1 5 2 2" on four lines)

Comment: What you did in edit two: I need the "3 1 2 1 5 2 2" all on the first line, he needs to start a second line after that, and then print "3 1 2 1 5 2 2" again (given that the input file then also has "3 5 2 2" on its second line; your input now only has 1 line, mine has multiple lines).

Comment: instead of long disccusion in comments, can you post your expected output by editing the question for clarification

Comment: Yes, I just did that :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using `sed` by replacing the first space by the string you want.

```
sed 's/ / 1 2 1 /' file
```

(OR)

With `awk` by replacing the first field(`$1`):

```
awk '{$1=$1 " 1 2 1"}1' file
```

(I prefer the `sed` solution since it has less characters).

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there, you just need to store the first column in a temporary variable:

```
{
  head=$1; # Store $1 in head, used later in printf
  $1=""; # Empty $1, so that $0 will not contain first column
  printf "%s 1 2 1%s\n", head, $0
}
```

And a full script:

```
echo "3 5 2 2" | awk '{head=$1;$1="";printf "%s 1 2 1%s\n", head, $0}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution with `awk`:

```
awk '{sub(/.*/, "1 2 1 "$2, $2)}1' File
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
3 1 2 1 5 2 2
```

Substitute the 2nd field with "1 2 1" followed by 2nd field itself.